# Restrict users from seeing the leads and opportunities of other users

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Usually in a company, inside Dynamics Sales Hub, one salesperson can see the leads and opportunities of others. My manager has asked me to reconfigure it in a way that only the managers can see the leads and opportunities of others, i.e. salespeople will not be able to see each others' leads and opportunities. I tried checking users, teams and security roles inside security settings menu of Sales Hub. Didn't find anything useful there.
How can this be done?
Please help.
Thank You!

Comment: you need to configure the security role so selected users can only access their own records

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom role for salesperson and change the `Read` privilege to `userowned` the one which looks as (*yellow mountain*) as below, and then no one else can see it.

You can also think of doing the same for `Create`,`Write`, `Delete`, `Append`, `AppendTo`, `Assign` & `Share` to say only owner can do it.

The same is true for `Lead` and other entities. And do make sure that other's roles are not granting the `business Unit` level privilege.

[image]